# Reindexing a multiindex in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to reindex a 2-level multiindex pandas dataframe. Data struct looks like this:

```
In [1]: df.head(5)


Out [1]:                                arrivals    departs
station         datetime
S1              2014-03-03 07:45:00     1           1
                2014-03-03 09:00:00     2           1
                2014-03-03 11:45:00     1           1
                2014-03-04 08:45:00     1           1
                2014-03-04 09:45:00     2           1
```

I want to fill `datetime` gaps with 15 minute intervals, but when I call

```
In [2]: df.reindex(pd.date_range(start='2014-03-03 07:45:00', 
                   end='2014-03-04 07:45:00', freq='15min'), level=1)
```

I get the exact same dataframe. I expected something like the following

```
Out [2]:                                arrivals    departs
station         datetime
S1              2014-03-03 07:45:00     1           1 <-- original row
                2014-03-03 08:00:00     0           0 <-- filled in row
                2014-03-03 08:15:00     0           0 <-- filled in
                2014-03-03 08:30:00     0           0 <-- filled in
                2014-03-03 08:45:00     0           0 <-- filled in
                2014-03-03 09:00:00     2           1 <-- original
                etc...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn it back into a simple datetimeindex and fill the gaps:

```
df = (df.unstack(level=0)
        .reindex(pd.date_range(start='2014-03-03 07:45:00', 
                   end='2014-03-04 07:45:00', freq='15min')))


df = df.fillna(0)  # for the data, 0 is the desired value

df.stack('station').swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with duplicated values in index. Once you remove `station` from the index, you get duplicated values for datetime. When trying to reindex I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Correct, I changed the answer to use stack instead

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Just had to use `swaplevel(0,1)` instead of `swaplevel()`, but it works just how it should. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that `stack` has a `dropna` parameter which can obviously be set to False